# Поворот в css3

Tags: jquery, css3, html, css

Нужно повернуть (flip) body вокруг оси y, и заменить на другую (например, как в jquery mobile). Как это сделать на css?

Comment: Вот тут почитайте: [CSS3](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp).

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(12deg) translate(-4px, -600px);
/* WebKit */
-webkit-transform: rotate(12deg) translate(-4px, -600px);
/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(12deg) translate(-4px, -600px);
/* Standard */
transform: rotate(12deg) translate(-4px, -600px);
```

цифры сугубо например. в таком виде работать не будет.
повернёте, а потом js ом поменяйте текст..

Только зачем? Скриптом проще же

Answer (score 0):

[Flip! A jQuery plugin](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/):

> Flip - это плагин jQuery, который может легко переверачивать элементы в четырех направлениях.